# Change Base class field value from Derived

Tags: c#, class, reflection, base-class, inherited

I have a question if it is possible to change field value of the base class, from derived class. In my case, i have two classes base class with windows form `RichTextBox`, and I want use derived class to clear `RichTextBox`.

Initialize `RichTextBox`:

```
        this.rtfCode.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 26);
        this.rtfCode.Name = "rtfCode";
        this.rtfCode.ShowSelectionMargin = true;
        this.rtfCode.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 96);
        this.rtfCode.TabIndex = 1;
        this.rtfCode.Text = "some text";
```

Base class:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.rtfCode.Text);
        DerivedClass f = new DerivedClass();
        Console.WriteLine(f.rtfCode.Text);
    }
}
```

My Derived class

```
    class DerivedClass:Program
{
    public DerivedClass()
    {
        base.rtfCode.Clear();
    }
}
```

when i execute program and press the `button` in `RichTextBox`  i still see text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Program a = new Program(); // a is an instance of Program
Console.WriteLine(a.rtfCode.Text);
DerivedClass f = new DerivedClass();// f is an instance of DerivedClass, which has nothing to do with a
Console.WriteLine(a.rtfCode.Text);
```

`a` and `f` are not the same instance. The fact that DerivedClass... derives from Program doesn't change anything to this.

You have to replace the last line by

```
Console.WriteLine(f.rtfCode.Text);
```